# How to keep new symbolic value for subs remain through Matlab Code

Tags: matlab, symbols

I am using subs function in Matlab after I solve for unknown symbols x and y in terms of known symbols a and b.  After solving for x and y in terms of a and b I would like Matlab to use a and b instead of x and y.  See code below:

```
clc
clear all
syms a b real;
syms x y real;
eqns = [x + 2*y + 4*b == 5*a;
       y == 3*b];
vars = [x,y];
solution = solve(eqns,vars);
x = subs(x,solution.x)
y = subs(y,solution.y)
tst = 5*vars
```

The output for this code is:
x = 5*a - 10*b

y = 3*b

tst=[ 5*x, 5*y]

I would like to get my last answer in terms of a and b. I assume that the line where I used subs for x and y should change it, but it did not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your `vars` vector after the `subs`:

```
clc
clear all
syms a b real;
syms x y real;
eqns = [x + 2*y + 4*b == 5*a;
       y == 3*b];
vars = [x,y];
solution = solve(eqns,vars);
x = subs(x,solution.x)
y = subs(y,solution.y)
vars = [x,y];
tst = 5*vars
```